# how I can determine if user bought a item by in-app purchase on ios

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-developer

Is it possible through developper apple dashboard or other legal systems to know if a user of my ios app has bought a product?
I tried asking apple, and he sent me this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/
but:

1. Do I also track the user's name / email?
2. are there other ways?
   thank you

Comment: Apple won't provide you any personal details of purchasers. If the user has an account in your app then you can record purchases against that user account in your own code.

Comment: Thx, but what kinds of information are sent through appstoreservernotifications?

Comment: The information is contained in the documentation you linked to. It varies depending on the transaction. A renewal ultimately contains https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/jwsrenewalinfodecodedpayload  You never get the user identifier. You need to record the `originalTransactionId` and use that to correlate events

Comment: So i need to ask my developper to modify the app? So when the user buy something, send this originalTransactionId to my server and associate it to the user data? right?